# Shell script not killing nc process when quitting

Tags: bash, process, sh, netcat, honeypot

I'm trying to create a simple honeypot using shell scripting. The script uses a while loop to keep a `nc` from stopping when the client closes the connection.
I wrote a function to kill all processes, including the script itself, to make sure that netcat will stop listening after the script is closed.

When I start the script, 3 processes `honeypot.sh` and 1 process `n` are created, when I close the script using `ctrl-c` and check the `ps -a`, the 3 `honeypot.sh` are gone, but the single `nc` is still there, and I have to kill it manually using `killall -nc`.

One interesting thing about this last `nc` process, is that even when the script is closed, I am still able to connect to the server, it even shows the banner, but this time, when I close the connection, the `nc` disappear and the server goes down as it should. - I wanted the server to close fully when the script closes.

Can someone show me what I'm doing wrong?

```
#! /usr/bin/bash

port="$1"
honeypot_pid=()
touch honeypot.log

# Handle SIGNI and kill created processes
function ctrl_c()
{
    #kill "$honeypot_pid"
#   wait
#   cleanup
#   exit 1
    echo -e "\nEncerrando o servidor..."
    for pid in "${honeypot_pid[@]}"; do
        kill "$pid"
    done
    killall honeypot.sh
    exit 1
}

# Netcat server
server ()
{
    while true; do
        ( echo -e "--------" $(date) "--------\n" ; nc -vnlp $port < banner.txt) >>  honeypot.log 2>&1
    honeypot_pid+=($!)
    done &
}

# Handles ctrl-c
trap ctrl_c INT

echo "Initializing server..."

ifconfig
server

# Show real time log
tail -f ./honeypot.log
```

Comment: You're not backgrounding anything before `honeypot_pid+=($!)`, are you actually adding anything to the array?

Comment: I checked and you're right, I checked with `echo $honeypot_pid`  and the array wasn't showing anything, then I put it after the `done &` and now it shows an PID number.
 Now I noticed that the PID number stored is related to the `honeypot.sh` process, not the `nc`, which is the one that remains running after the script is closed. I have no idea on how to get the `nc` PID number.

Comment: Check Ed's answer but the tl;dr is to put the `nc` in the background (some form of `nc <args> &`) rather than putting the loop in the background. It's not even clear to me that you need a loop unless your intention is to automatically restart `nc` in case it dies.

Answer (score 1):

I think by this:

```
server ()
{
    while true; do
        ( echo -e "--------" $(date) "--------\n" ; nc -vnlp $port < banner.txt) >>  honeypot.log 2>&1
    honeypot_pid+=($!)
    done &
}
```

you probably meant to do this:

```
server()
{
    while true; do
        {
            echo -e "-------- $(date) --------\n"
            nc -vnlp "$port" < banner.txt
        } >>  honeypot.log 2>&1
    done &
    honeypot_pid+=($!)
}
```

or similar (check the syntax) so you have a loop running in a separate background process, with `nc` running in the foreground of that process, and honeypot_pid containing the PID of that process so you can kill it later.

That would still leave `nc` orphaned though - I expect you can resolve that by [enabling job control](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/196603/133219) for that background process:

```
server()
{
    set -m
    while true; do
        {
            echo -e "-------- $(date) --------\n"
            nc -vnlp "$port" < banner.txt
        } >>  honeypot.log 2>&1
    done &
    honeypot_pid+=($!)
    set +m
}
```

and changing the kill command from `kill "$pid"` to `kill -- -"$pid"` so that [kills the process group](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/14815/133219) of that process so it'll kill the subshell and anything being run from it, rather than just the subshell.

Answer (score 1):

This might be a cleaner implementation of what you're attempting:

```
#!/bin/bash
port=$1
ctrl_c() {
  [[ "$honeypot_pid" ]] && kill "$honeypot_pid"
  [[ "$tail_pid" ]] && kill "$tail_pid"
  killall honeypot.sh
}
trap ctrl_c INT

server() {
  printf '%s\n' "-------- $(date) --------"
  nc -vlnp "$port" < banner.txt &
  honeypot_pid=$!
}
touch honeypot.log
tail -f honeypot.log &
tail_pid=$!

while true ; do
  server >> honeypot.log 2>&1
  wait
  # here you might normally do something like:
  # echo "Restarting server..."
  # sleep 1
done
```

The goal is:

- Put `nc` in the background, instead of the loop
- Get the pid of the backgrounded command
- Use `wait` to stop the program until that command exits. `wait` can be interrupted by a signal, so you'll still get into your trap handler if someone presses Ctrl+C.
- If the backgrounded command exits by something other than the user pressing Ctrl+C, the loop will restart and you'll get a new command with its associated pid.
- Once the user presses Ctrl+C, the pid of the current command will be signaled to exit.

In your original implementation, you don't have `nc` in the background. You have `while true` in the background, essentially a subshell running your `nc` in its own foreground. Since you don't have the pid of that `nc` you can't kill it, but when you do `killall honeypot.sh` you kill the subshell around it leaving its child orphaned (parent pid = 1) with no parent left to manage it.